# How can I combine three strings into a single string in SQL that is emebeded at the top of Classic ASP page?

Tags: sql, asp-classic

For example, I'm trying to combine "String1" "String2" and "String3" to read as "String1 / String2 / String3". Then I'd like to convert that string to a date as each of my three string variables are month, day, and year saved separately.

I'm trying to do something like the following:

`SELECT *, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, month + "/" + day + "/" + year), 101) AS ActualDate`

I actually have a functional page already connected to a database. I'm trying to add additional search features, and for that I need to be able to compare an actual date with search parameters when all I have are three varchars. What I'm looking for is how to convert those three varchars in to one string, and then convert that to a date in the SQL. The code example I used above does not work when added to my SQL statement.  I don't' know if it's a simple syntax error, or if this isn't even the correct was to go about making the date.

Comment: i think you should show the actual query you have, instead of `something like..`

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet opens a connection to a database, execute a sql statement and write the returned field "ActualDate" into Response stream object.

I edited to add a very simple way to create a sql statement from the request parameters and then submit to the database. Please bear in mind that this is not a "beautifull" way and that you still need to guarantee that the parameters will not break the SQL.

```vb
<%
' get parameters from request
Dim parDay : parDay = cLng(Request("DAY"))
Dim parMon : parMon = cLng(Request("MONTH"))
Dim parYea : parYea = cLng(Request("YEAR"))

' IMPORTANT: add your own validation here

' open connection to database
Dim cnn : Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnn.Open("paste-your-db-connection-string-here")

' create recordset and assign to the connection
Dim rs : Set rs  = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs.ActiveConnection = cnn

' execute the statement and get its results using the recordset
Dim sql : sql = "SELECT *"
+ "FROM myTable"
+ "WHERE ActualDate > '" + parYea + "-" + parMon + "-"  + parDay + "';"
rs.Open(sql)

' write to the page
Response.Write(rs.("ActualDate"))
%>
```

Comment: I actually have a functional page already connected to a database. I'm trying to add additional search features, and for that I need to be able to compare an actual date with search parameters when all I have are three varchars. What I'm looking for is how to convert those three varchars in to one string, and then convert that to a date. The code example I used above and this example do not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to varchar values in a SQL query then you can use the + operator to concatenate them.

`'varchar' + 'varchar' + 'varchar'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Table1.*, 
(Table1.month + "/" + Table1.day + "/" + Table1.year) AS ActualDate
FROM Table1
```

If that doesn't cover it, look into using `GROUP_CONCAT` or other concatenating functions.